# Safest way to interact with model with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, security, model

I'm just wondering what is the most secure way to query my database when using code igniter.
Currently my model queries look like:

```
function getDetails($filename){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("mydatabase");
    $this->db->where("filename",$filename);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

or alternatively:

```
 function getUsername($username){ 
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        return $row->username;
    }

}
```

But is this the safest way? If not, does anyone know a more secure way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the active record classes is the best way, which you are already doing. I'm not sure why you are doing the if/else in your first method because they both appear to do the same thing. Also in the second one you could do `->limit(1)` then `$query->row()` so you only get one row. But apart from those minor issues it looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by "safe" and "secure". Assuming "safe" means vars are checked for being valid (meaning defined and set) then `getDetails()` is safe and `getUsername()` not so much.

The first is made safe with the line `if($query->num_rows()>0){` where you assert that the query returned some rows. One suggestion, consider this structure instead.

```
if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result();
}
else
{
    return NULL;
    //return $query->result(); would return an empty array which might be OK
    //if you account for that possibility in the calling function.
    //But if that's the case why the `if` statement? 
    //Skip the conditional and just return $query->result()
}
```

Or, instead of an `if` condition this could be more elegantly written using a ternary operator.

```
return $query->num_rows()>0 ? $query->result() : NULL;
```

I like to return NULL from models when the query produces no results. The return value is checked in the calling function like so

```
$result = $this->model_name->getDetails($filename);
if(empty(result))
{
   //handle the lack of data
} 
else 
{
   //do stuff with $result  
}
```

The PHP function `empty()` is nice cause it consider all the following to be empty: `NULL`, `FALSE`, an empty array, an empty string (""), `0` (0 as an integer), `0.0`(0 as a float), "0" (0 as a string). Most bases are then covered.

`getUsername($username)` is less safe because there may not be any rows returned by the query. That might result in an unset var in the function that is assigning the return from this one. Without any row the `foreach` won't run and `getUsername($username)` will return void. That's not necessarily a problem if you use `isset()` on the var assigned by the call to `getUsername($username)`.

As far as "secure" is concerned you're in good shape because using `where()` eg `$this->db->where('username', $username);` will automatically escape the input value.  User input is always a primary point of concern and possible attack.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I usually return 'FALSE' if there are no results. Are there any advantages to returning NULL instead?

Comment: The advantage comes if you are using `isset()` to check results. If a `$x = FALSE;` then `isset($x)` returns `TRUE`. But if `$x = NULL;` then `isset($x)` returns `FALSE`. If you're using `empty()` then both `$x = NULL` and `$x = FALSE` will return `TRUE`.  BUT in the case of a database return it's entirely possible to get and array with an empty item in it e.g. `$x = array( array());` which `empty($x)` will report as FALSE. Technically not an empty var, but of little use.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response @cartalot ! great answers from yourself an DFriend!

Answer (score 1):

Dfriend has some great points. I'm just going to pile on because this is such a basic pattern its valuable to really dig into.

You wrote:

```
if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return $query->result(); // editors note: no no no 
    }
```

I'm not going to be as polite as Dfriend - do not do this. Its confusing to look at and is not accurate. Here is one way:

```
if($query->num_rows()>0){

        return $query;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

One consideration is that if you are returning a result with multiple rows - then return just $query from the model. Then you have options for later methods and your view.

In the controller you **always want to check if you got anything back from the database**. Even if you have records, and your php server is working the database connection can go down. Dfriends way is very good, this is slightly different. Basically we are checking for the not condition first. If no results were found then we go to a method for that condition. That keeps your methods focused and easy to understand.

```
  // if the query result was false, then show a different view
   if( ! $query = $this->model->getDetails($searchTerm)
    {
        $this->showNoResultsFor($searchTerm); 
    } 
    // if you return just $query you have all these options available 
    // in your controller and/or view 
    else
    {
     // get one row
      $query->row() ;     

      // get number of records returned 
      $query->num_rows(); 

      // the records as object 
      $query->result() ; 

      // pass query to your view
      $data['query'] = $query ; 

       // pass the number of found results to view
      $data['found'] = $query->num_rows();

       // pass just the records to view
       $data['results'] = $query->result() ;  

    }
```

For example showing the number of records returned in your view file - is very common. Or needing to grab one record from a group of them. So thats why I'm suggesting to return $query. Finally by now you have realized that this is awkward

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        return $row->username; // editors note: no no and no
    }
```

If you are searching for something that you know has to be unique like a table record id - and there can only be one result - then check for one result and return the row.

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return $query->row();
}
else{ return false; }
```

Comment: One additional comment on `foreach ($query->result() as $row)`. Again no, no and no. Do not call a function as the first argument do `foreach`. Instead to `$result = $query->result(); foreach($result as $row){...`

Comment: Thanks for the response @DFriend ! I'll take all of this into consideration.. thanks for the help